# Change NSLayoutConstraint constant not working in layoutSubviews

Tags: ios, iphone, autolayout

I am trying to change a UIButton's width when the view animates to landscape mode. But the method is called because I set a break point there, but the button's width doesn't change. I add a IBOutlet constraint to button's width named: globalButtonWidthConstraint.

My current code :

```
- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;
    CGFloat screenH = screenSize.height;
    CGFloat screenW = screenSize.width;
    BOOL isLandscape =  !(self.frame.size.width == (screenW*(screenW<screenH))+(screenH*(screenW>screenH)));

    if (isLandscape) {
        self.globalButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 100;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } else {
        self.globalButtonWidthConstraint.constant = 47;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    }
}
```

Comment: make it sizetofitcontent

Comment: no need to set width constraints and change constats

Comment: I believe you can use `UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarOrientation]` to get the current screen orientation (landscape/portrait), then you can check using `if(orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) { ... } else { ... }`

Answer (score 4):

Try updating constraint constant in "viewDidLayoutSubviews".

```
 -(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{

   [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];

  // Update constraint constant

   [self.view layoutSubviews];

}
```

It worked for me.

**EDIT:** Make sure that there is no other constraints that conflicting this width constraint.

Comment: But I am changing the constraint in UIView, not in view controller. viewDidLayoutSubviews is a method of view controller.

Comment: So view is added using "addSubview"? 'layoutSubviews' is getting called on orientation change? Then check 2 things. 1.Whether 'isLandscape' returns proper value. 2.Is there any other constraints that conflicting this width constraint.

Comment: Yeah. I found out there are other constraints that conflicting this width constraint. I am setting equal width to these two buttons. So, changing one won't work. I have to change both of them altogether. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: Thank you. It work for me. In my case, I use UITableViewCell

Comment: Thanks for the edit about the conflicting constraints. Helpful!