# UITableViewAutomaticDimension works not as expected. Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uitableviewautomaticdimension

After reading Ray Wenderlich [guide](https://www.raywenderlich.com/1067-self-sizing-table-view-cells) for "Self-sizing Table View Cells" as well as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30299319/why-uitableviewautomaticdimension-not-working) and answers to it, I've decided to ask all of you for a help.

Have a programmically created cell:

```
import UIKit

class NotesCell: UITableViewCell {
lazy private var cellCaption: UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

    return label
}()

func configure(with note: NotesModel) {
    cellCaption.text = note.name

    contentView.addSubview(cellCaption)
}

override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        cellCaption.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
        cellCaption.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
        cellCaption.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
//            cellCaption.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
cellCaption.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
            ])

//        cellCaption.sizeToFit()
//        cellCaption.layoutIfNeeded()
}
}
```

The table view controller uses UITableViewAutomaticDimension in the delegate methods:

```
extension NotesTableViewController {
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, estimatedHeightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

}

As a result, the longest caption is indicated fully, but the cell anyway has the same height as all other.

[image]

Some update!

I've already tried to put into viewDidLoad() following code:

```
tableView.rowHeight = 44
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
```

with enabling delegate methods and disabling them as well. The result is the same :(

Comment: Try this in viewDidLoad(): `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50`

Comment: I think the screenshot attached is from simulator, Please check in real device.

Comment: Unfortunately, in the real device the result is also the same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're doing a number of things wrong, but the *main* point is your use of `greaterThanOrEqualTo:`.

Instead, it should be:

```
cellCaption.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
```

Also, your current code is *adding a new label as a subview* every time you set the text. Cells are reused, so you only want to add the label when the cell is created.

Next, the correct properties for the table are:

```
    tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
```

Put those two lines in `viewDidLoad()` of your table view controller, and ***do not*** implement `heightForRowAt` or `estimatedHeightForRowAt` functions. You can delete your `extension` entirely.

And finally, you only need to set the constraints once. Definitely ***NOT*** in `layoutSubviews()`.

Here's a full example:

```
//
//  NotesTableViewController.swift
//
//  Created by Don Mag on 8/29/18.
//

import UIKit

class NotesModel: NSObject {
    var name: String = ""
}

class NotesCell: UITableViewCell {
    lazy private var cellCaption: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()

        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20, weight: UIFont.Weight.medium)
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

        return label
    }()

    func configure(with note: NotesModel) {
        cellCaption.text = note.name
    }

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() -> Void {

        contentView.addSubview(cellCaption)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            cellCaption.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: 8),
            cellCaption.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 8),
            cellCaption.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -8),
            cellCaption.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8),
            ])

    }

}

class NotesTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 8
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "NotesCell", for: indexPath) as! NotesCell

        let m = NotesModel()

        if indexPath.row == 3 {
            m.name = "This is a very long caption. It will demonstrate how the cell height is auto-sized when the text is long enough to wrap to multiple lines."
        } else {
            m.name = "Caption \(indexPath.row)"
        }

        cell.configure(with: m)

        return cell
    }

}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: As far as I understand, the main reason of my fault was using of layoutSubviews()?

Comment: No.. there was really no *main* fault... You had the wrong constraint, you were adding subviews wrong, and you had `.rowHeight` and `.estimatedRowHeight` wrong. (sorry, don't mean to be saying wrong, wrong, wrong...)

Comment: No problem! So ... there are just a lot of mistakes that lead to such an unexpected result.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend not to use the Delegate-Methods for your needs.

Just try setting this in your `viewDidLoad`:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
// set estimatedRowHeight to whatever is the fallBack rowHeight
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

This always works for me. Let me know if it helps :)

Comment: @YuriIvashin if this doesn't work you should have a deeper look into your constraints. The cell needs to be able to calculate the height of your cell without a doubt.

Comment: Constraints are easy as it possible. Tried to change priority for top an bottom constraint. Result is the same

Comment: @YuriIvashin Did you have a look here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27288507/change-nslayoutconstraint-constant-not-working-in-layoutsubviews

Comment: Have put into tableViewController:     override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        tableView.layoutSubviews()
    } as well as calling self.layoutIfNeeded() inside the cell's layoutSubviews. Result is the same

Comment: If you want me to help further show it in your question. Sounds like you put it in TableViewController but you should put it in your TableViewCell i guess.

Comment: I do appreciate your help. But take into account what whis is a Table view Cell. Value of type 'UITableViewCell' has no member 'viewDidLayoutSubviews'

Comment: @YuriIvashin Oh sorry. You are right. Anyway: Did you try to place your code from layoutSubviews in configure after you add the subview? (I think layoutSubviews is triggered before you add the subview itself)

Comment: I've put NSLayoutConstraint.activate and self.layoutIfNeeded() into he configure function with fully commented layoutSubviews(). Result is the same

Answer (score 0):

Update the following line:

```
cellCaption.bottomAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
            ])
```

to:

```
cellCaption.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: -8)
            ])
```

and add following in viewDidLoad:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Following steps may solve your problem:

1) set top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints for the UILabel in the cell like below:
[image]

2)  configure tableview:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
```

Comment: The cell is created programmically

Comment: @YuriIvashin did you also add all constraints to cell's label programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In Swift 5:

```
func configureTableView() {
        myTableView.rowHeight =  UITableView.automaticDimension
        myTableView.estimatedRowHeight = 44
    }
```

Keep in mind that if the `.estimatedRowHeight` is not correct, Swift will do the math for you. Finally, call this method in the `viewDidLoad()`